# How to generate separators between buttons inside a search box in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a input search box which has two buttons on the right end of the search box. In future I would be adding more buttons on the right. So I am thinking of auto generating the button separators whenever a button has another button on its right side. Is this possible to be done only with CSS?

Currently I am only generating the button separator as a small little pip between two buttons using the following css rules. But this is specific to the RESET button only. I have another button named "search button" next to the reset button. Now if I add a new button name "Image button", I need to have a separator auto generated. I didn't want to have a separate `div` for the separators. Is it possible?

```
.search-field__reset-button::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 1.5rem;
  content: '';
  border-right: 1rem solid black;
}
```

Comment: give them all a common class and then use last child to remove the border of the last button or leave that class off the last button

Comment: @Pete solid, simple and clean. OP please do this! Please consider forming an answer with that solution

Answer (score 0):

```
button{
  color:red;
}

button + button{
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

try this

Comment: this will work when you will have button after button

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.